# Fullpage Js Not a full page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, parallax, fullpage.js

I am using a great library `fullpage.js`. It works perfectly, however I need to implement the following case.

I don't need my full page to be fullypage scrollable. I mean that when I try to apply `fullpage` it blocks all other scroll events. 
I need to get the following result.

1. User can scroll freely sections until he/she reaches the section that should be fullpage scrollable only.
2. It has for instance 5 slides
3. After slides are shown it should release full page scroll and allow user to scroll further without any issue
4. In case user scrolls up again it should capture user's scroll when he/she reaches the section again.

Is it possible to implement using FullPage Js ?

Comment: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html  |  

https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#examples

Comment: Have you written any code / checked the documentation for those options?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

You can simulate that by using the `scrollOverflow` option though.
See [this example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

So basically, put all your content in the last section and you'll get an scroll bar there when using `scrollOverflow:true`.